# JavaScript ActiveXObject is not defined in browser console

Tags: javascript, php, ole, activexobject, amibroker

I would like to ask wether this ActivexObject can be accessible using web server through PHP. Because when I include the javascript, it shows that the activexobject is not defined(when using browser), while in edge/ie11 it says "SCRIPT429: Automation server can't create object". But if I double click that JS file, it works perfectly fine. For further information, I'm using this because an application called "Amibroker" have the OLE.
here'is the JS that I'm using

```
var AB = new ActiveXObject("Broker.Application");
    AB.ActiveDocument.Name = "UNVR.JK";
    AW = AB.ActiveWindow;
    AW.ExportImage( "D:\\Export\\UNVR.jpg", 1920, 1080 );
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: @AlexK. I already tried that too, but it says "SCRIPT429: Automation server can't create object"

Comment: added related tag

Comment: anybody know this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

First: `ActiveXObject` only exists in Internet Explorer. It is not available in other browsers, even in Microsoft Edge.

Second: The `Broker.Application` ActiveX control is probably not marked as [safe for scripting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751977(v=vs.85).aspx#ov_script). This means that it cannot be used from within a web page, as it may pose a security threat.

Generally speaking, any ActiveX control that can read or write files at specific paths on the user's hard disk will not be marked as safe for scripting.

Comment: so how am I able to just call that script within in php / ajax ? I already tried that using IE also give the same result